# How to detect a drop in regularity / increase in spontaneity of time data?

Tags: time-series, change-point, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have been tasked with detecting changes in regularity for multiple datasets. Each dataset is linked to a different type of event, and each dataset consists of a few hundred timestamps representing each time the event occurred.

For any given type of event, there will be a rough level of regularity (e.g. the first dataset's event may happen daily, the second may happen weekly, etc.) but none are 100% regular - some have little-no regularity, some of them are almost 100% regular. All of them have a few outliers (which I'm not particularly concerned with)

For some of the datasets, a trend exists but then degrades (eg the event happened weekly during jan-jun, but then degraded to biweekly during jun-dec).

I've been trying to design an algorithm that can flag whenever there's a noticeable, statistically significant change in a dataset's regularity but nothing has worked so far. My intuition is that a rule-based approach that takes the fourier transform of subsets of the data is my best bet, but I can't work out how to best make that happen. If anyone can suggest a good algorithm / library / approach then it would be much appreciated, because I've been trying this for days now and I can't get it to click.

Comment: First you must define how to measure *regularity* or *spontaneity*. By variance? ... ten loo into changepoint analysis.  Or maybe *control charts*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are really modeling *intervals* between events. From your description it sounds like the trends do not follow smooth periods (Fourier) or autoregressive patterns. So the model could be: at what date(s) is there evidence of a change in average period between events? This is an intercept change point. There are [a lot of change point packages](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/articles/packages.html) out there for R. Using `mcp`, you could do:

```r
# Make some data with 7 and 14 days intervals. Then compute diff.
df = data.frame(day = c(seq(1, 180, 7), seq(194, 365, 14)) + rnorm(39, 0, sd = 2))
df$diff = c(NA, diff(df$day))

# Model it as two intercepts and sample it
model = list(
  diff ~ 1,  # Intercept
  ~ 1  # Intercept
)

library(mcp)
fit = mcp(model, data = df, par_x = "day")
```

Now you can see the posterior distribution for the change point, and some sample lines from the posterior:

```r
plot(fit)
```

[image]

Or in table format:

```r
> summary(fit)

Population-level parameters:
    name  mean lower upper Rhat n.eff
    cp_1 183.2 166.7 205.7    1  2987
   int_1   7.2   5.4   8.9    1  4922
   int_2  14.4  12.1  16.7    1  4793
 sigma_1   4.2   3.2   5.2    1  4058
```

You can do loads of other stuff as well, including comparing models. See the `mcp` [website](https://lindeloev.github.io/) for more examples.